# Ruby On Rails self saving in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, self

I have a function in my model that changes is as follows:

```
  def compare
        self.dirty = 1 if self.dirty == 0
        compare_recursive(0, MergeDigestTree.all)
        self.dirty = 0;
  end
```

Do I have to call self.save or is it fine like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is open to two interpretations:

- Do you *have to* call `self.save` so the record is saved at this point? **yes**, because an attribute assignation does not commit the change to the database.
- Are you *forced* to call `self.save` and thus save the record? **no**. It's ok for a method to change the instance and do not save it. I usually prefer this one, as you give more freedom to the caller.

Whatever the case, document the method accordingly.

Comment: Does the scope of self carry over to other functions though.  Like when I go to compare_recursive will dirty still be 1

Comment: other methods will see the dirty version of the object with the new values for "dirty" (unless they reload the instance, which they shouldn't unless there is a good reason)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to save it yourself, yes. Though I don't see what that method is really doing. :)

Comment: Trying to be mathematic when it comes to relatively simple questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you should have to call save once changes are made, at some point after this function, if not within this function...

so if you're using this function manually in your app...

```
resource.compare()
resource.save
```

Would be fine if you don't want to put the `self.save` **in** the compare function.

Comment: What if compare recursive relies on dirty being 1 so it knows not to compare to itself.  Will it remain like that or will it only be valid in that function

Comment: it should remain as long as it resides in memory, which would be the life of the request.